# reading folder directory content on android java processing

Tags: java, android, file, directory, processing

There are a few questions on stack which ask exactly this and yet none of the answers seem to resolve the issue in any way. Please note I am using the processing environment to code, which uses java, but with a wrapper. All java code works natively though.

Code is running on android 10 huawei mate 20 emui 10.

Here is my code. Only the first for loop returns any values, returning "emulated", "sdcard0", and "self", however the subsequent folders return null with the same functions. Permissions have been set in the manifest and in the pde app.

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Build ;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
Permission rStorage,wStorage;

void setup(){
  rStorage = new Permission(this,"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
  rStorage = new Permission(this,"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
  //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory("storage/").toString();
  //println("Files", "Path: " + path);
  File directory = new File("storage/");
  File[] files = directory.listFiles();
  if(files!=null){
    println("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        println("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
    }
  }else println("Files",null);
  
   directory = new File("storage/emulated");
   files = directory.listFiles();
  if(files!=null){
    println("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        println("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
    }
  }else println("Files emulated",null);
  
  directory = new File("storage/sdcard0");
   files = directory.listFiles();
  if(files!=null){
    println("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        println("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
    }
  }else println("Files sdcard0",null);
  
  directory = new File("storage/self/");
   files = directory.listFiles();
  if(files!=null){
    println("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        println("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
    }
  }else println("Files self",null);
};

void draw(){
  
};
```

my permission class

```
public class Permission{
  
  PApplet parent;
  
  public boolean requestedPortraitImage = false;

  public Permission(PApplet pParent,String permissionName) {
    parent = pParent;
    parent.requestPermission("android.permission."+permissionName, "onPermissionResult", this);
    println(permissionName);
  };

  public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
    if (!granted) {
      PApplet.println("User did not grant camera permission. Camera is disabled.");
    }
  };

};
```

Comment: Android version of used device/emulator please.

Comment: `File directory = new File("storage/");` That should be `File directory = new File("/storage");` Not that it would change things ;-)   directory = new File("/storage/emulated");

Comment: Code is running on android 10 huawei mate 20 emui 10.

Comment: @blackapps that one actually works, only the others return null

Comment: Ok. This is intended behaviour. Sad for you. Sad for us. You better try new File("/storage/emulated/0"); But on an Android 10 device listFiles() will also return null. Unless you requested legacy external storage in manifest.